# Specifying the legendTemplate in Chart.js when using asp (classic)

Tags: asp-classic, chart.js

The suggested legendTemplate for chart.js is:

```
legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
```

However my chart is in a (classic) *.asp file, so the '<%' is being interpreted as the start of server-side asp. Is there a way to 'escape' the '<%' and '%>'?

Comment: i've added an option in my fork of chart js to change these to what ever you want (well actually within reason what ever you want, the easiest option is to change them to [[ and ]]), it's explained in this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497274/how-do-i-change-the-interpolator-used-in-chart-js/25506542#25506542

Comment: Thanks Quince! To other asp users, I ended up using Response.Write() and separating the "<%" (e.g., "<" & "%"). It was enough to fool the server, but Quince's change is much cleaner.

Comment: cheers, you should add your comment as an answer and mark as the answer so other people can easily find it if they are searching for the same thing about chart js and asp

Answer (score 1):

See Quince's comment (where you can change the start/end template interpolators) and my comment about separating the "<" and "%" for solutions to this.